# come back to my previous point in PDF

Tags: pdf, evince

suppose you reading a PDF with document viewer now you want to search a word in PDF you press CTRL + F search your word.the list appear you click on one of them see the passage . So now you want to come back and countinue reading pervios part . Is there any way in document viewer ? If not do you know a PDF reader from repository to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bookmark the page first via 'Bookmarks'->'Add bookmark' menu before doing your search. After the search, just select it from the bookmarks menu and it will take you back to that page.

---

**NOTE**

As of now, there is no interface to delete them once added. See [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotations-delete.html).
However, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95042/how-to-delete-an-annotation-in-evince) has already addressed the issue and provided a way out.

Comment: +1 so cool, is there a better PDF viwer?

Comment: @alex That comes down to personal preference. I use Evince but you can also install Adobe Reader from the software center.